# What's the correct use of \author when multiple authors?

Tags: formatting, titles

Working on a project, the article we are writing is written by me and someone else. How should I fill the `\author`?

What about `\author{LASTNAME1, FIRSTNAME1 \& LASTNAME2, FIRSTNAME2}`? It doesn't convince me, but it might be correct.

Is there any better way to do that?

P.S: I'm using the `article` class and the authors will be shown once with `\maketitle{}`.

Answer (score 258, accepted):

The [`\maketitle`](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/latex2e-help-texinfo/latex2e.html#g_t_005cmaketitle) command with `\author` allows a simple separation of two (or more) authors by using the `\and` command. See code below for some inspiration.

```
\documentclass[11pt,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\author{
  LastName1, FirstName1\\
  \texttt{first1.last1@xxxxx.com}
  \and
  LastName2, FirstName2\\
  \texttt{first2.last2@xxxxx.com}
}
\title{Usage of the \texttt{\textbackslash author} command}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: +1 for `\and`, which I've not seen in many years of using latex.  I've not needed this (and will not likely ever use it) because the journals for which I write each have their own way of handling such things.

Comment: Just curiosity, what's that english option in `\documentclass`?

Comment: @Tomas: A language option passed to the »babel« package.

Comment: Ohh. So there is no need to use `\usepackage[english]{babel}` anymore?

Comment: @Tomas: I prefer to give language options globally. So other packages are also able to use them if applicable.

Comment: Is there a way to do exactly this but have the authors separated vertically, instead of being listed horizontally?

Comment: @ForkrulAssail Of course, just use ```\\[3ex]``` instead of `\and` ;)

Comment: How to add affiliation in between name and email?

Answer (score -1):

```
\documentclass[twoside,english]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{\protect\theoremname}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
% specify here the journal
\journal{Example: Nuclear Physics B}

% use this if you need line numbers
%\usepackage{lineno}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\providecommand{\theoremname}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}{}

\title{This is a specimen title\tnoteref{t1,t2}}

\tnotetext[t1]{This document is a collaborative effort.}

\tnotetext[t2]{The second title footnote which is a longer longer than the first
one and with an intention to fill in up more than one line while formatting.}

\author[rvt]{C.V.~Radhakrishnan\fnref{fn1}\corref{cor1}\corref{cor2}}

\ead{cvr@river-valley.com}

\author[rvt,focal]{K.~Bazargan\fnref{fn2}}

\ead[url]{http://www.elsevier.com}

\fntext[fn1]{This is the specimen author footnote.}

\fntext[fn2]{Another author footnote, but a little more longer.}

\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}

\cortext[cor2]{Principal corresponding author}

\address[rvt]{River Valley Technologies, SJP Building, Cotton Hills, Trivandrum,
Kerala, India 695014}

\address[focal]{River Valley Technologies, 9, Browns Court, Kennford, Exeter, United
Kingdom}
\begin{abstract}
Abstract, should normally be not longer than 200 words.
\end{abstract}
\begin{keyword}
quadruple exiton \sep polariton \sep WGM \PACS 71.35.-y \sep 71.35.Lk
\sep 71.36.+c \MSC[2008]23-557
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}{}


\section{Introduction}

Bla bla,



\end{document}
```

Comment: this answer is using `elsaricle` not the `article` document class.