# Multiple authors in a Journal style (llncs) Document

Tags: titles, templates

How to display multiple authors in a journal style e.g. `\documentclass{llncs}` document?

The solution suggested in [What's the correct use of \author when multiple authors?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4805/whats-the-correct-use-of-author-when-multiple-authors/4806#4806) does not work for me, as `\and` is not working in my document.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Please refer to the documentation for the `llncs` class (the file `llncsdoc.pdf` found inside [llncs2e.zip](ftp://ftp.springernature.com/cs-proceeding/llncs/llncs2e.zip)):

> Now the name(s) of the author(s) must
> be given:
>
> ```
> \author{<author(s) name(s)>}
> ```
>
> Numbers referring to different
> addresses or affiliations are to be
> attached to each author with the
> `\inst{<no>}` command. If there is more
> than one author, the order is up to
> you; the `\and` command provides for the
> separation[...]

> [...]Next the address(es) of institute(s),
> company etc. is (are) required. If
> there is more than one address, the
> entries are numbered automatically
> with \and, in the order in which you
> type them. Please make sure that the
> numbers match those placed next to to
> the authors’ names to reflect the
> affiliation.

A little example:

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\begin{document}

\title{Hamiltonian Mechanics unter besonderer Ber\"ucksichtigung der
h\"ohreren Lehranstalten}

\author{Ivar Ekeland\inst{1} \and Roger Temam\inst{2}
Jeffrey Dean \and David Grove \and Craig Chambers \and Kim~B.~Bruce \and
Elsa Bertino}

\institute{Princeton University, Princeton NJ 08544, USA,\\
\email{I.Ekeland@princeton.edu},\\ WWW home page:
\texttt{http://users/\homedir iekeland/web/welcome.html}
\and
Universit\'{e} de Paris-Sud,
Laboratoire d'Analyse Num\'{e}rique, B\^{a}timent 425,\\
F-91405 Orsay Cedex, France}

\maketitle     

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The particular template file I got has below line and therefore it does not work.

`\def\author#1{\begin{center}{\sc #1\par}\end{center}}`

Comment: It didn't work because you didn't follow the instructions. Don't use centering here.

Comment: Off-topic, but this is a really ugly template in my opinion.