# Sorting references, and displaying "References" instead of "Bibliography"

Tags: bibliographies, sorting, lncs

In my `\documentclass{llncs}`, I use

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[sort]{natbib}
```

to sort the references of my document. While the above achieves sorting, the section entitled "Bibliography" appears at the end of the document, starting with a new page.

I would like to have the writing "References" immediately after the main body which ends in the first third of a page. So, the section "References" should start from there, and references should remain sorted in the main body. 
In addition, I would like the sorted references to appear without a space after comma, e.g., `[1,2,3]`, intead of `[1, 2, 3]`.

How could this be achieved?

Comment: I think that this question clearly requieres a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @tohecz In the meantime, perhaps you could make a suggestion on alternative that I might consider. The aim is to have sorted references appearing without a space after comma, and with the "References" section starting immediately after the main document body.

Comment: Well, the reason to make MWE is that (1) everybody who wants to help you has to do it himself and if you do it, you save them time that they can invest into helping you, (2) the solution often depends on some settings that people often omit without MWE and often include in MWE.

Comment: another reason for a mwe is that the answer is different if you're using a document class for a book/report as opposed to an article.

Comment: Aren't these two unrelated questions?

Comment: Do you mean the documentclass mentioned in the question [multiple-authors-in-a-journal-style-llncs-document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20292/multiple-authors-in-a-journal-style-llncs-document)? Then follow please page 21 ff in the documentation `llncsdoc.pdf`. Try document class option `[oribibl]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean the documentclass mentioned in the [question multiple-authors-in-a-journal-style-llncs-document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20292/multiple-authors-in-a-journal-style-llncs-document)? Then follow please page 21 ff in the documentation `llncsdoc.pdf`. Try document class option `[oribibl]`. Without an complete MWE I or we can only guess. You will find on page 21:

> There is a special BibTEX style for LLNCS that works along with the
>   class: `splncs.bst` – call for it with a line
>   `\bibliographystyle{splncs}`. If you plan to use another BibTEX style
>   you are customed to, please specify the option `[oribibl]` in the
>   documentclass line, like:
>
> `\documentclass[oribibl]{llncs}`
>
> This will
>   retain the original LATEX code for the bibliographic environment and
>   the `\cite` mechanism that many BibTEX applications rely on.