# Problem with \maketitle and \affil (authblk package)

Tags: titles, affiliation, authblk

**edit: Thanks to the help of a colleague of mine, I found the solution. Thanks to all the helpers.
here is the link:
[Multiple authors in a Journal style (llncs) Document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20292/multiple-authors-in-a-journal-style-llncs-document)

I'm using TeXstudio and wish to submit a paper, but having a problem with compiling my Tex code. Before using `\affil[1]`, `\affil[2]` etc. I had no problem, but I need it to be in this form (when I use the \and, \thanks form it works).

I fought this problem for hours now without a solution.
I'll be happy for some help.
Thank you so much.

I get the following errors:

```
'Illegal parameter number in definition of \toc@uthor. \maketitle'
'Illegal parameter number in definition of \toc@uthor. \maketitle'
'Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a. \maketitle'
'Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a. \maketitle'
```

when I run the following code:

```
\documentclass[english]{llncs}

\pagenumbering{plain}  
\usepackage{amssymb} %add a personalized operator
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\usepackage{authblk}
\title{Paper's title}
\author[1,2]{A}
\author[1,2]{B}
\author[2,3,4]{C}
\author[1,2]{D}
\affil[1]{institute A}
\affil[2]{institute B}
\affil[3]{institute C}
\affil[4]{institute D}
\institute{}
\renewcommand\Authands{ and }
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I doubt that `authblk` is compatible with `llncs`.

Comment: Thank you! :)

If `authblk` does not compatible to `llncs`, there is any alternative to `authblk`?

Comment: OK
Here is the solution, thanks to a colleague's help. Thank you very much.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20292/multiple-authors-in-a-journal-style-llncs-document

Comment: If you have to use `llncs`, do as the class requires.