# Is it possible to have more than one author?

Tags: titles

Could you help me with these questions:

- How do you add 2 authors to a document that uses the article document class?
- Are there commands to specify where the authors are placed at on the paper?

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{Example Article}
\author{Author 1 \\ Author 2}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

As you can see I hard-code the authors into two lines, but there might be a better way?

Comment: take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4805/whats-the-correct-use-of-author-when-multiple-authors

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001) When you refer to authors, do you mean entries in the `\author{...}` macro (typeset via the `\maketitle` command), or do mean names in the `author` field of a bibliographic entry of type `@article`? Please advise.

Comment: What @dcmst says. Or if it's a `\documentclass` for a journal, just follow their instructions, they surely have some.

Comment: In general you can use `\author{foo \and faa}`.

Comment: Thanks for all the quick replies, I will look at that @dmst.

Comment: the suggestions given so far are good, but do be aware that document classes for journals from different publishers may handle author input differently (e.g., `amsart` is different from `article`).  so do read the publisher's instructions.